# How to fill in a website form with a date?

Tags: vba, excel, post, web-scraping

I am trying to download data from http://www.sem-o.com/MarketData/Pages/DynamicReports.aspx (free account needed). I managed to select on report and fire event.

I am trying to input the date. I tried `getelementbyid`, `getelementsbytagname`, even `document.all`.

This [page](http://www.analystcave.com/web-scraping-tutorial/) explains the difference between get and post methods for a form. In this case, the post method seems to be used in the HTML, but I cannot find my way through it.

The code I have written:

```vb
Sub acces()
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim link As String
    Dim startdate As Date
    Dim enddate As Date
    link = "http://www.sem-o.com/MarketData/Pages/DynamicReports.aspx"
    startdate = #1/1/2014#
    enddate = #3/31/2014#
    
    For i = startdate To enddate
        Y = Year(i)
        If Len(Day(i)) = 1 Then
            Daynum = "0" & Day(i)
        ElseIf Len(Day(i)) = 2 Then
            Daynum = Day(i)
        End If
        If Len(Month(i)) = 1 Then
            MonthNum = "0" & Month(i)
        ElseIf Len(Day(i)) = 2 Then
            MonthNum = Month(i)
        End If
    
        Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        ie.Visible = True
        ie.navigate (link)
    
        newHour = Hour(Now())
        newMinute = Minute(Now())
        newSecond = Second(Now()) + 3
        waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)
        Application.Wait waitTime
    
        Set SelectElem = ie.document.all("ctl00$ctl00$g_f5e6fa98_faa2_4210_85e9_780934d96ab8$cmbSelectReport")
        SelectElem.Value = "/SEMO Dynamic Reports/Dynamic Reporting - Tables/Energy Data/System Frequency"
        SelectElem.FireEvent ("onchange")
    
        newHour = Hour(Now())
        newMinute = Minute(Now())
        newSecond = Second(Now()) + 3
        waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)
        Application.Wait waitTime
    
        'here where I cannot make it work
    
        Set ObjTable = ie.document.all("input")
        While a < ObjTable.Length
    
            If x = ObjTable(a).all("ctl00_ctl00_g_9ab92c0a_eb10_4b6c_ad1b_7277cbdab462_prm_GetFromDate_prm_GetFromDateDate") Then
                x = MonthNum & "/" & Daynum & "/" & Y
            End If
            a = a + 1
        Wend
    Next
End Sub
```

How do I reach the right item to fill in the dates?

I need to download several reports for long periods of time and the website finds data series too heavy if asking for a whole month.

Comment: you could have shared some HTML to make a better [mcve]